# Stack Overflow app should warn me when I accidentally click the Back button while typing an answer

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-app

I have installed the Stack Overflow app. When I click on a question and begin writing an answer, and click on the Back button by mistake, it doesn't ask me to save my changes, or give me any warning that I'll be leaving the page.

Comment: In the Stack Exchange app you even get a warning for _comments_.

Comment: Seems like ideally it should just save the answer automatically and let you continue where you left off when you return to the answer form, just like it does on the desktop site.

Comment: Did you actually lose the content? On the website, your unsubmitted answer is saved temporarily, at least in some cases. @Ajedi32 It does on the web. Dunno about the app.

Comment: Well played on your reasoning.

Comment: The auto-save-to-localstorage is one of Stack Overflow's best features. I've lost many a paragraph on many sites due to accidental navigating/closing/etc. on my part, but never on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow knows I'm a stupid git who needs some help :-)

Comment: I disagree with the warning; just auto-save instead, it's more friendly.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thank Paul for that ;)

Comment: @PaulDraper Love that edit xD

Comment: @Clonkex, Bard Larson didn't :(

Comment: @PaulDraper I noticed :(

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm missing something here. As far as I know, there is possible way to start writing an answer and then lose the contents of your draft. Are you using the iOS app or the Android app? What flow is causing this to happen for you?

On **iOS**, when you're writing a new answer the page looks like this:

[image: iOS new answer flow]

If the answer text field isn't blank, and you hit Cancel, you are blocked at this dialog until you respond:

[image: iOS answer draft prompt]

Note that on iOS you can also grab and slide the entire header row down, to minimize your in-progress answer while you look back on the question.

On **Android**, when you are writing a new answer the page looks like this:

[image: Android new answer flow]

If the answer text field isn't blank, and you hit back (either the actual back button or the icon in the header), you go back to the question view:

[image: Android question view with draft]

Note the orange pencil icon on this page now, it wasn't visible until you had an answer draft (which you do now). The "Add Answer" button at the bottom of the list has also turned into "Continue Answer".

Both apps allow you to flip back between the question (and other answers) while writing your answer, without losing anything. Yes, there's a difference between the iOS and Android flows (automatic saving on Back/Cancel vs being able to minimize the page and being prompted when hitting Back/Cancel), but neither loses any content.

So I think what's happening is you're using the Android app, and it's not visible that a draft was saved?

If that's the case, for the first few times the automatic answer draft saving occurs I could show the user a "Answer saved, you can resume it at any time" or something, but I'm not sure if that's actually what's happening (and I also thought the big orange button with the pencil was pretty obviously stating that).

Comment: The big orange pencil button, though very obvious, is not very obvious in its meaning. I'm not an android user so maybe there's an established convention I'm unaware of, but I wouldn't have jumped to the conclusion that it would continue editing a draft question. Also "Continue answer" is clear, but missable if the user decides to give up due to assuming their existing text is lost. Perhaps an animation showing the draft answer collapse into the orange pencil button when clicking "back" would help demonstrate that it isn't being discarded?

Comment: @Dave yeah I am thinking about adding a [Snackbar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage) with "Draft saved" for the first few times this flow happens. I'm curious to see if people who have used the Android app think it's confusing, since the orange pencil animating into view is eye-catching (and on Android the paradigm is long-press to view action description, which it does). All that said -- I still don't know if this is what the O.P. is talking about.